# Cannot install Kubuntu 12.04.3 with wubi

Tags: installation, wubi, kubuntu

Im trying to install kubuntu 12 with wubi, but I get

> Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO

everytime I try to install.

My ISO name is

> kubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386

Im running Windows 7 x86, I also tried the parameter "--32bit" but nothing works.

The last lines of my log:

> err=[Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found 10-14 21:50 DEBUG 
>   downloader: downloading
>   http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/daily-live/current/precise-desktop-i386.metalink
>
> > C:\ubuntu\install 10-14 21:51 ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot download metalink file2
> >     http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/daily-live/current/precise-desktop-i386.metalink
> >     err=[Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found 10-14 21:51 DEBUG  TaskList:
> >
> > #### Finished get_metalink 10-14 21:51 ERROR  TaskList: Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in **call**
>   File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 595, in get_iso
>   File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 406, in download_iso
>   Exception: Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO 10-14
>   21:51 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist 10-14 21:51 DEBUG 
>   TaskList: # Finished tasklist 10-14 21:51 ERROR  root: Cannot download
>   the metalink and therefore the ISO Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run   File
>   "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task   File
>   "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer   File
>   "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in **call**   File
>   "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 595, in get_iso   File
>   "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 406, in download_iso
>   Exception: Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO

Comment: Have you tried checking the Kubuntu iso for errors (before boot)? Also have verified MD5 checksums? It is possible the iso is corrupted...

Comment: Did you verify the integrity of the iso file by checking its md5 hash?

Answer (score 0):

Your wubi.exe is not up to date. For 12.04.3 you need rev.279.

Comment: Could you include where to get an updated version?